# Which options could be a solution for droplet with0 bytes of space

Tags: php, digital-ocean, laravel-7, droplet

I have a problem with my current **web application**, **Laravel 7.3 hosted in one droplet** in digital ocean, since my droplet has run out of space and because of this my application regularly crashes.

I have found information about *creating/purchasing a volume of 100 GB or more to later point in the fstab file* to said volume in some of the folders that use the most space within my Laravel project structure, but I still don't know what folder it could be.

With the vast experience of all the recurring specialists in this forum, **I would like to know if there are other options or if this volume option is the most suitable for my current problem**

I am trying to recover the proper functioning of my web application and give it more time to live.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [sf] would be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: “but I still don't know what folder it could be” - the general pattern is to [mount to a common location](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/volumes/how-to/mount/), often a folder of your choosing in `/mnt`, and then [linking that folder to your application’s folder](https://superuser.com/a/1326174). If/when you upgrade this to newer/modern PHP, it might be better to create a new droplet that just has more space, too.